# xslt analyze-string alternative in version 1.0

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

So my XSLT 2.0 looks like this:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="creation_date" regex="([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
        <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(4)"/>
        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(5)"/>
        <xsl:text>:00.000+01:00</xsl:text>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

How could I do something like that in version 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract substring as in e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="s" select="creation_date"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="substring($s, 7, 4)"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($s, 4, 2)"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($s, 1, 2)"/>
        <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($s, 12, 2)"/>
        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($s, 15, 2)"/>
        <xsl:text>:00.000+01:00</xsl:text>
```

That way you will get the substrings extracted but there are no checks that they are made up of digits.